# How do I help NPCs that keeps yelling "Help me" who die when I don't do anything?

Tags: dishonored

These are the generic NPCs that keeps yelling "Help me". In order to prevent their death I just choke them as choked NPCs don't seem to die for no reason. This will be my way of saving them until I figure out how to properly do it.

There are no rats or guards nearby that could have cause their death... they just die.

Comment: Where are they, exactly?

Comment: I have encountered one of them during my first visit to distillery (its location is right after the location of the first guard... it has a staircase to the bridge) and some more inside the building of high overseer. 

The first one was the most confusing of them all as the NPC was completely fine and talkable when I first see her. When I returned to her location something was wrong with her. She just died for no reason.

Comment: Yes, if you poison the distillery then a bunch of them turn into weepers and kill all the others. There might still be a couple of weepers even if you don't.

Comment: Shouldn’t poisoning distillery only effect the later mission (where we meet slackjaw)? “Help me” yellings were in High Overseer mission.